# How to download private files from S3 during EMR bootstrap?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rubygems, amazon-emr

I'm trying to use some of the great AwsLabs bootstrap Ruby scripts, to set up some services. Unfortunately the examples seem to assume you are using public buckets, and use curl to download those files.

Since I cannot make our S3 objects public at this time, I'm trying to download them by sending the access/private keys in my Ruby script. However, the aws-sdk ruby gem seems to require at least Ruby version 1.9.2 (nokogiri). On our EMR instance, the version is 1.8.7

So at this point, what would be the best option? Assuming I cannot make the files public?

Comment: you can use it's Java SDK if you have the liberty to have java 1.6+ installed on your machines. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingJava.html

Comment: You mean use the Java SDK to get the file from S3, and then run the ruby bootstrap script?

Comment: Yeah, create a simple jar and execute it using a simple bash script as a bootstrap action.

Comment: @Amar got it , I'll try that thanks! Just need to make sure to download the file from S3 before the bootstrap script runs